# Angular2 TypeError: e(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have an issue with Bootstrap daterangepicker using this wrapper for Angular2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-daterangepicker

I included required scripts and stylesheet in html and declared DateRangePickerDirective in a module.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Everything works fine in initial angular-cli project, but I can't move this solution to our enterprise project, when page with picker loads I get error:

```
TypeError: e(...).daterangepicker is not a function
    at DateRangePickerDirective.ngOnInit (index.js:20)
    at AppView._View_DaterangepickerComponent0.detectChangesInternal (DaterangepickerComponent.ngfactory.js:50)
    at AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:298)
    at AppView._View_RequestComponent0.detectChangesInternal (RequestComponent.ngfactory.js:360)
    at AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:298)
    at AppView.detectChangesInternal (view.js:283)
    at AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:290)
```

Here is function which causes exception:

```
DateRangePickerDirective.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
        $(this.elementRef.nativeElement)
            .daterangepicker(this.options, this.dateCallback.bind(this));
    };
```

In addition, if I place a breakpoint on this line and evaluate it in browser console, It works, component loads. I'm new to Angular and little confused with it, maybe something wrong with versions of our libraries? Here is our package.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist vendor && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "karma start",
    "posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
    "test-watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
    "postinstall": "gulp gentelella",
    "preinstall": "npm config set https-proxy=http://... && npm config set proxy=http://..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-daterangepicker": "0.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "gentelella": "1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.26",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^3.4.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.1.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Any clue what could be the cause?

**UPD:** Also noticed, when it's not working, the previously mentioned function called twice and call stack differs from case when everything is Ok. Call stacks:
[starting from left: wrong call no error, wrong call with error, ok call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUbnv.png)

Comment: Are you sure `this.elementRef.nativeElement` is already present during `ngOnInit ` ? Isn't `ngAfterViewInit` a better hook when accessing DOM elements? The fact that it works when you stop on a breakpoint indicates that race conditions might be occurring.

Comment: @Matey I think yes, it's present, at least when I inspect it in debug. Anyway, it happens in library script, I can't change anything there. I also noticed that call stacks are differ in cases when it works and not. Added screenshots to my question.

Comment: Inspecting in debug is not the correct way to determine race conditions. While you stop the execution at a breakpoint within the event the parallel thread fills the object and it's therefore not null anymore. Could you insert `console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement);` before `$(this.elementRef.nativeElement)` and let us know what it prints?

Answer (score 1):

daterangepicker dep is missing.
npm install --save daterangepicker